# Angular - Module '"ngx-intl-tel-input"' has no exported member 'TooltipLabel'

Tags: angular

In my Angular-11, I have:

```
import { SearchCountryField, TooltipLabel, CountryISO, PhoneNumberFormat } from 'ngx-intl-tel-input';
```

But this error came up:

> Module '"ngx-intl-tel-input"' has no exported member 'TooltipLabel'

and it highlights only:

> TooltipLabel

How do I get this sorted out?

Thanks

Comment: Can you specify which version of `ngx-intl-tel-input` are you used?

Comment: @YongShun - "ngx-intl-tel-input": "^3.1.1"

Comment: It seems the `TooltipLabel` is removed from new version. https://github.com/webcat12345/ngx-intl-tel-input/issues/373#issuecomment-808138398

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this [GitHub issue comment](https://github.com/webcat12345/ngx-intl-tel-input/issues/373#issuecomment-808138398),

> TooltipLabel has been removed in the latest update. Ref: #336

Latest [ngx-intl-tel-input](https://github.com/webcat12345/ngx-intl-tel-input) (version 3.1.1) had remove `Tooltip`. Hence you have to **remove `TooltipLabel` from `ngx-intl-tel-input` import**.

```js
import { SearchCountryField, CountryISO, PhoneNumberFormat } from 'ngx-intl-tel-input';
```

---

### Reference(s)

[Fully remove reference to tooltip](https://github.com/webcat12345/ngx-intl-tel-input/commit/a654dc71f7af309c3e7706bd6fcaa71052bf2b1a)